# Creating serial number from and serial number to in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have in one column range of number like 001,002,003........010
I want to create a range in two column from->001 to->010

input

| Sr no | serial | extra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 1111 |
| 2 | 002 | 1111 |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| 10 | 010 | 1111 |
| 11 | 011 | 1112 |
| 12 | 012 | 1112 |

output

| Sr no | From | to | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 010 | 1111 |
| 2 | 011 | 012 | 1112 |

Tried using python it works but we want it in sql queries

Comment: Isn't this just `MIN`/`MAX` (and `ROW_NUMBER`)..?

Comment: Will extra values always be the same within a Sr no group?

Comment: yes, the extra column is the differentiator for closing the range. It will be same for a sr no group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    MIN([Sr no]) OVER (PARTITION BY [extra])  [Sr no], 
    MIN([serial]) OVER (PARTITION BY [extra])  [From], 
    MAX([serial]) OVER (PARTITION BY [extra])  [To], 
    [extra]
FROM 
    Table1
GROUP BY 
    [extra], [serial]
ORDER BY 
    [Sr no]
```

Hope This work....

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GROUP BY` and `dense_rank` as follows:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by extra) as sr_no,
       min(serial) as [from],
       max(serial) as [to]
       extra
  from your_table
group by extra;
```